# if loop inside with file open: unexpected EOF while parsing

Tags: python, file, file-handling

I am trying to modify a json file content based on flag passed.
Here is the code snippet

```
import json
import argparse

def updateConfFile(confFileFilePath, connDetail, resetproxy):
    with open(confFileFilePath, "r") as confFile:
        jsonData = json.load(confFile)
        jsonData["CloudConnectMgmtConfig"]["connDetail"] = eval(connDetail)
        if (resetProxy == "true"):
            jsonData["CloudConnectMgmtConfig"]["connCfg"]["proxyEnabled"] = eval("false")
            jsonData["CloudConnectMgmtConfig"]["connCfg"]["proxyHost"] = eval("")

    return jsonData


## Main
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("connfilepath")
parser.add_argument("connDetail", nargs='?', const=1, default="{}")
parser.add_argument("resetProxy", nargs='?', const=1, default="false")
args = parser.parse_args()

jsonData=updateConfFile(args.connfilepath, args.connDetail, args.resetProxy)

# Write a provisioning json
with open(args.connfilepath, 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(jsonData, outfile)
```

script call

```
python updateDataConnConf.py /path/to/conffile.conf "" true
```

I am getting the following error

```
  File "updateDataConnConf.py", line 7, in updateConfFile
    jsonData["CloudConnectMgmtConfig"]["connDetail"] = eval(connDetail)
  File "<string>", line 0

    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

i am using Python 2.7.5

Comment: Where are you calling the `updateConfFile` function?

Comment: I am calling it within the same script 
```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("dataconnConfPath")
parser.add_argument("connDetail", nargs='?', const=1, default="{}")
parser.add_argument("resetProxy", nargs='?', const=1, default="false")
args = parser.parse_args()

jsonData=updateConfFile(args.dataconnConfPath, args.connDetail, args.resetProxy)
```

Comment: I mean, can you show the call? What arguments are you passing to the function? I suspect it may be something about the string passed to `eval(connDetail)`.

Comment: And when you run the script from the command line, what arguments do you pass? Please edit your question to include these details.

Comment: i tried removing eval as well, it did not help .. a bit of search it has to do with closing of blocks , but i dont see any issues in closing `with` block or `if` block

Comment: Your error looks to me like a result of `eval("")`, i.e. with an empty string.

Comment: Please, update your question to include all important relevant information. Don't post important info in comments.

Comment: It looks like there is problem with your json file. Probably inside it there is problem with quotes. Make sure it's valid JSON. And there is no need of all these `eval()` calla

Comment: the issue is occurring only when i add the if block .. otherwise its perfectly working script

Comment: Your issue **IS** with the string you're passing to `eval()`, definitly and without any doubt (the error message makes it quite clear). And chances are you don't need `eval()` at all, but since you didn't post a _proper_ [mcve] we can't really help further.